# AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer audio have different length

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I record with AVAudioRecorder, then pause it, print the currentTime, stop it and close it.

When I play the audio and print the duration of it, it is always different than the currentTime.

How is that possible? I don't do anything with the audio after pausing it besides saving it so how is there a different length?

```
recorder.pause()
print(recorder.currentTime) //e.g. 1.14
recorder.stop()
print(Manager.getAudioFileLength(url)) //e.g. 1.31

do {
    try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("error: \(error)")
}
print(player.duration) //e.g. 1.25
```

And in Manager

```
class Manager {
static func getAudioFileLength(url : NSURL) -> Float64 {
    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url)
    let audioDuration = audioAsset.duration
    let audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)
    return audioDurationSeconds
}
```

}

Comment: please show your code so that we can see if you have any problems in how it is implemented, we cannot see any problems with what your doing if we cannot see what you've done?

Comment: `duration` is deprecated in iOS 9 by the way.   Anyway.. this is interesting, but what is your point?  How does `playableDuration` (also deprecated) compare?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset/duration) of AVAsset (superclass of AVURLAsset):

> If providesPreciseDurationAndTiming is false, a best-available estimate of the duration is returned. ... If providesPreciseDurationAndTiming is true the absolute precision, at whatever processing cost that entails–and cost can be significant for certain media formats, such as .mpg.